# How would I apply trapazoidal integration to a matrix in R

Tags: r, integration

I am brand new to coding in R and this may be a complete beginner question. How would I apply a trapazoidal integration to an imported set of data? I have been trying on a basic function before I use the experimental data.

```
    >x=c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
    >y=c(0,1,4,9,16,25)
    > A= data.frame(x,y)
    > A
    x  y
    1 0  0
    2 1  1
    3 2  4
    4 3  9
    5 4 16
    6 5 25
    >myfunct= function(n) {return(sum((y[-length(y)]+y[-1]))/2)}
```

After this is where I run into issues

```
    >apply (A,c(0,1),myfunct)
    > [1] 42.5 42.5 42.5 42.5 42.5 42.5
```

I just need to have one value outputted, and I can't seem to find much on if I can or how I would do that.

Comment: You define the anonymous function with `n` and then you have `y`?  Did you meant `myfunct= function(y) {return(sum((y[-length(y)]+y[-1]))/2)}` and `apply(A, 1, myfunct)`

Comment: Also, perhaps `(A[-1] + A[-length(A)])/length(A)`

Comment: That would make more sense than what I did, wouldn't it. I just entered in both of those adjustments and I got [1] 35 35 35 35 35 35. The answer seems to be even more off than the original

Comment: For me, I am not getting 35 35 35, etc.